# Your apple id is also attached to other itunes providers (1622)

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

When I try to upload my build I get this error message:

> Your apple id is also attached to other iTunes providers. You will
>   need to create a new user on iTunes Connect to submit content to this
>   account. Please contact us if you have questions or need help (1622)

My account is **not** connected to other accounts and I managed to upload my build yesterday it worked. I have read other threads and they do not fit my error.

I´m using Swift in my application if that´s relevant.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: You're not alone. https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/231534#231534

Comment: There seems to be some internal errors at Apple, I just tried it myself: > The iTunes Store is experiencing an internal server error. See
> http://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/ for information about major
> outages. The iTunes Store is experiencing an internal server error.
> See http://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/ for information about
> major outages. > This action could not be completed. Try again. (-22421) The validation seems to be working though.

Comment: Looks like its working again now